# What type of fruit tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]

This tree is growing in Escambia county(in panhandle of Fl). It is, roughly measured by comparing to our 6ft tall fence, about 10-12ft tall. It is growing in my neighbors yard but it grows over the fence, dropping the fruits into our yard when they are ripe every late summer. I am assuming it is a fruit tree, but I don't know what kind. Are the fruits safe to eat? It is probably 7-10yrs old, but I'm no tree age expert. The flowers were a dark color, maybe a brown/maroon? I didn't think to take pictures of it when they were blooming so maybe that was the flower color just before turning to fruits. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a [persimmon (Diospyros or Diospiros)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persimmon). The fruits can be quite tasty when fully ripe though some variety's fruit continues to be quite astringent even when ripe. The [Fuyu cultivar](http://www.fast-growing-trees.com/Fuyu-Persimmon-Tree.htm?gclid=CjwKEAjw6_q5BRCOp-Hj-IfHwncSJABMtDaiTWcR-7vffqnFv5NCy1LiO41TzFFnybK_3mbLrGbdHBoCLv_w_wcB) grows rapidly, is self-fertile, and produces sweet fruits. I'm sorry, but I cannot tell you what variety/cultivar you have - there is a multitude of them.